# Could a planet experiencing tidal locking have a habitable area?

Tags: temperature, astrophysics, planets, biology, tidal-effect

I wonder if it would be possible that, on a planet that always shows the same face towards the sun, there is a habitable area for some life-form similar to that of the Earth. I guess, since one face would be extremely hot and the other extremely dark and cold, that area should be a ring that delimited both sides.

Would the temperature be warm and constant there? How wide would such a ring be?

Comment: related: https://physics.stackexchange.com/q/29182/25301, https://physics.stackexchange.com/q/29293/25301, https://physics.stackexchange.com/q/43797/25301